# Core Data fetch in AppIntent is crashing when app is running in background

Tags: swift, sirishortcuts, appintents

I’m building an AppIntent Shortcut and want to perform fetch requests of my apps Core Data to feed the Shortcut with the data.

### My Code

Core Data Handling:

```
class HomesHandler: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    static let shared = HomesHandler()
    
    let objectContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext

    func fetchAllHomes() -> [Home] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Home> = Home.fetchRequest()
        
        // PERFORM FETCH
        do {
            return try objectContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching Homes: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

AppIntent Code:

```
struct HomeIntentQuery: EntityPropertyQuery {
    // Populates the list when the user taps on a parameter that accepts a Home.
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [HomeIntentEntity] {
        // Fetch All Homes
        // Sorted by non-archived first
        let allHomes = HomesHandler.shared.fetchAllHomes().sorted(by: { !$0.isArchived && $1.isArchived })
        
        // Map Core Data to AppEntity
        return allHomes.map { home in
            HomeIntentEntity(id: home.id,
                             title: home.wrappedTitle,
                             isArchived: home.isArchived)
        }
    }

    // …
```

Intent Entity to Core Data Bridge:

```
struct HomeIntentEntity: AppEntity, Identifiable {
    // Required to conform to Identifiable
    var id: UUID
    
    // Properties mirrored from Core Data
    @Property(title: "Title") var title: String
    @Property(title: "Is Archived") var isArchived: Bool
    
    
    // …
}
```

Core Data Persistence Controller:

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    // An initializer to load Core Data,
    // optionally able to use an in-memory store.
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        // Access actual Core Data file
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MeterStats")
        
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Core Data Loading Error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

---

## Problem

The problem I have is that the code crashes with a *EXC_BREAKPOINT* whenever the app is running in the background. Once the app is closed the fetch request just works fine. How can that be?

I’ve already tried to wrap the `do try objectContext.fetch(request)` into `objectContext.performAndWait`. Though, that leads to a crash inside the `.sorted(by:)` when trying to access `.isArchived`

The strange thing is that this works perfectly fine at this [great GitHub example](https://github.com/mralexhay/Booky) by Alex Hay. He uses the same code to do the [fetch request](https://github.com/mralexhay/Booky/blob/c2f85f52640257754b2297b2753d870f42a598e4/Data/BookManager.swift#L18-L26) as well as the [AppIntent code](https://github.com/mralexhay/Booky/blob/c2f85f52640257754b2297b2753d870f42a598e4/Shortcuts/ShortcutsBookEntity.swift#L97-L108).

**So, how do I have to handle fetch requests that are running inside AppIntents correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that for some reason the fetch request was performed outside the apps main thread. Not sure why it works in the [Booky example](https://github.com/mralexhay/Booky) without it, though.

To fix this issue, I’m now using the `try context.performAndWait {}` action to perform the fetch request inside. Important to note is to do the mapping from the Core Data Entity to the custom `AppEntity` inside the `performAndWait`! Otherwise it will lead to a crash when creating the `AppEntity` object.

```
struct HomeIntentQuery: EntityPropertyQuery {
    // Populates the list when the user taps on a parameter that accepts a Home.
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [HomeIntentEntity] {
        // Fetch All Homes
        // Sorted by non-archived first
        let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Home> = Home.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Home.isArchived, ascending: true)]
        
        var allHomes: [HomeIntentEntity] = []
        try context.performAndWait {
            do {
                allHomes = try context.fetch(request).map { home in
                    // Map Core Data to AppEntity
                    HomeIntentEntity(id: home.id, title: home.wrappedTitle, isArchived: home.isArchived)
                }
            } catch {
                throw error
            }
        }

        return allHomes
    }

    // …
}
```